# Proof that $z+z^2$ is algebraic over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field

I need to show / or disprove, that if $z\in L$ for a Field extension $L\supseteq K$ is algebraic over $K$, then $z+z^2$ is also algebraic over $K$.

I thought of writing the expression $\sum_{i \in I} k_i(z+z^2)^i$ and forming it around to get a solution I can work with.. but I kinda doubt that this works after trying for a while..

can someone give a hint?

kind regards

Comment: Hint: an element $a$ is algebraic over $K$ if and only if $K(a)$ is a finite extension of $K$.

Comment: There is the proof mentioned in the answer. Are you looking for an explicit polynomial which $z+z^2$ satisfies?

Comment: no I dont need a special polynomial. But I do not quite understand the notation of the proof below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum and product of algebraic numbers are algebraic, to see this, if $a,b$ are algebraic, it is equivalent to $[K(a):K]$ is finite dimensional, $K(a,b):K(a)]$ is finite dimensional and $[K(a,b):K]\leq [K(a,b):K(a)][K(a):K]$, you deduce that $K(a,b)$ is algebraic.

Comment: Surely if OP knew this, they would not be stuck on this problem :) Edit: this comment might look a bit silly now that you've added more details

Comment: so I know $[K(z):K]$ is finite dimensional by stating $z$ is algebraic over $K$. how do I know $[K(z,z^2):K(z)]$ is final dimensional..

Comment: because $z^2=z.z$.

Comment: In fact $K(z)$ is an algebraic field, so it contains $z^2$.

Comment: sadly I did not learn about them yet :/ so $K(z)=\lbrace k_1+k_2\cdot z \rbrace$, and $K(z,z)=(K(z))(z)=\lbrace (k_1+k_2\cdot z)+(k_1+k_2\cdot z)\cdot z \rbrace$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $z$ is algebraic over $K$ means the $K\!$-algebra $K[z]$ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space. Observe that $K[z+z^2]$ is a subalgebra of $K[z]$.